# Apache Avro as a Built-in Data Source in Apache Spark 2.4

Tags: apache-spark

I recently read [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/30/apache-avro-as-a-built-in-data-source-in-apache-spark-2-4.html) article and tried out the example but when I run

```
val usersDF = spark.read.format("avro")
                        .load("examples/src/main/resources/users.avro")
```

But this gives me an error when I try to run it.

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Failed to find data source: avro. Avro is built-in but external data
>   source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per
>   the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide".;   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:647)

Comment: Feel free to comment the reason for your downvote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upon reading up [Apache Avro Data Source Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html), I figured build.sbt needs to be updated with a new dependency.

```
val sparkVersion = "2.4.0"
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-avro" % sparkVersion
```

Everything worked fine after this.