# Read/Load avro file from s3 using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, apache-zeppelin

Using AWS glue developer endpoint `Spark Version - 2.4` `Python Version- 3`

Code:
`df=spark.read.format("avro").load("s3://dataexport/users/prod-users.avro")`

Getting the following error message while trying to read avro file:
`Failed to find data source: avro. Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide".;`

Found the following links, but not helpful to resolve my issue

[https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html[Apache](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html%5BApache) Avro Data Source Guide][1]

[Apache Avro as a Built-in Data Source in Apache Spark 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604464/apache-avro-as-a-built-in-data-source-in-apache-spark-2-4)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to import that package

```
 org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0
```

Check which version you need [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-avro)

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported the package while starting the shell? If not you need to start a shell as below. Below package is applicable for spark 2.4+ version.

```
pyspark  --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0
```

Also write as below inside read.format:

```
df=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("s3://dataexport/users/prod-users.avro")
```

Note: For pyspark you need to write '**com.databricks.spark.avro**' instead of 'avro'.

Comment: we access AWS Developer instance from the following command `ssh -i <dev-endpoint-private-key.pem> glue@<public-address>` and don't explicitly start the shell